# How to read and display native contact list photo using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am building on the  Phonegap. 
Pretty nifty, in that I found  how to build a contact list.  I've 
finished the tutorial, and now want to add to it to better learn 
Phonegap.

What I would like to do is display the contact's primary photo on the 
item detail page. The contact photo is returning a url of "/var/ 
folders/45/xfgjqr4j59144x8gzq4gdrpw0000gn/T/photo_004.jpg". My 
question is how can I actually display that? I'm assuming the / 
var directory is not accessible via the img tag (as the image is not 
displaying), but I assume that file is accessible through a Phonegap 
API. I further assume that it is somehow through the File API. That's 
where my train of thought details and I can go no further.

Can anyone help me get back on track? Anyone have an example of how to 
display the image from the contact list?

Comment: I am not a PG user, but does `<img src= "/var/ folders/45/xfgjqr4j59144x8gzq4gdrpw0000gn/T/photo_004.jpg">` work? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Which version of PG are you using? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: PG 3.x version , I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link on [PhoneGap API File documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html). You could read the file as base64 string, and embed it in the HTML img tag:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Maybe like this, using PhoneGap 2.5, for example:

```
function loadImage(imgId, fileName){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function(fileSystem){
            fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, null,
                function(fileEntry) {
                    fileEntry.file(
                        function(file){
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                                var image = document.getElementById(imgId);
                                image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + evt.target.result; //You must specify the image format: png, gif, ...
                             };
                             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }
                        , fail);
                }
                , fail);
        }
        , fail);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Then, to load an image for a `img` node with `id="contact1"`:

```
loadImage("contact1", "/var/folders/45/xfgjqr4j59144x8gzq4gdrpw0000gn/T/photo_004.jpg");
```

It's just a vague idea, I haven't tested it yet.