# FileNotFound when trying to access contact photo with Cordova contacts plugin

Tags: cordova, contacts, android-contacts, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to display a contact's photo using Cordova 3.5.0 on Android.
I've tried the following solutions:

- [How to read and display native contact list photo using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045480/how-to-read-and-display-native-contact-list-photo-using-phonegap)
- [PhoneGap resolveLocalFileSystemURI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065494/phonegap-resolvelocalfilesystemuri/24589382)

All I get from the contacts plugin is an image in the form:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/909/photo
```

this works on Android 4.4 within emulator: you can just use it as

```
<img src="content://com.android.contacts/contacts/909/photo">
```

or read it as a file and copy locally (see question above).

On Android 4.1 on real device it will simply break with FileNotFoundException if I try to read as a file and will just fail to load the image if I place the reference within HTML.

Here are my plugins:

```
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.2.0 "PushPlugin"
org.apache.cordova.contacts 0.2.10 "Contacts"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.10 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.1.0 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.4 "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.media 0.2.11 "Media"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.11-dev "Network Information"
org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.9 "Vibration"
```